# How to check if type has index signature at runtime

Tags: typescript

I'm not sure if this makes any sense, because many types are objects in JavaScript, but here we go:

I want to implement a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards), which checks if the type implements [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types). How would one do that?

In other words, how to implement the body of this function:

```
function hasIndexSignature(o: complexunioninterface | { [index: string]: string }): o is { [index: string]: string } {
    return /* Help? */;
}
```

Considering many types are objects, is the correct implementation this:

```
function hasIndexSignature(o: complexunioninterface | { [index: string]: string }): o is { [index: string]: string } {
    return typeof o === "object";
}
```

One way would be to implement a type guard for `complexunioninterface` and just negate that, but I'm interested if implementing the type guard for the index signature would make any sense and if it is possible.

Comment: You probably can't. Why would you like to know something like that? Can you edit your question and add a real world scenario?

Comment: You might be able to make this work using the reflect-metadata API depending on what type info typescript auto-annotates there (and a type guard that checks for it), but other than that I'm with @NitzanTomer

Comment: The only thing that remotely makes sense is to enumerate all properties and check if each one is a string - that's what index signature `{ [index: string]: string }` basically means. Would that be good enough to distinguish from compexunioninterface or not - I have no idea.

Comment: Well, I've just began learning TypeScript. I found myself writing guards for union type `headers?: HeaderInit | { [index: string]: string };` of [node-fetch](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/4a3c0197cc63cffda7570844c3f6ebc9f4475587/node-fetch/node-fetch.d.ts#L23) to have type information inside my `if` and `else` blocks. In this case I just wrote a guard for `HeaderInit`, but as I'm learning, I was curious if it's possible to write a generic guard for `{ [index: string]: string }` and if it would make any sense. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm interested if implementing the type guard for the index signature would make any sense and if it is possible.

A custom type guard is *designed for the case when a compiler cannot infer advanced knowledge you have about the objects*.

So really, its up to you to decided how much of a test is sufficient. I would say go with your idea of `implement a type guard for complexunioninterface and just negate that,`