# Unsafe assignment of any value trying to transform properties on an object

Tags: typescript-eslint

I have something like this snippet:

```
function transformIt(value: any): any {
  ...
}

let foo: any = ...
if (typeof foo === 'object') {
  for (const property in value) {
    foo[property] = transformIt(foo[property])
  }
}
```

When I run eslint on this, it complains that there's an unsafe assignment of an any value but I can't figure out how to make it happy. Would appreciate any insight on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to check if type has index signature at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40114226/how-to-check-if-type-has-index-signature-at-runtime) has the answer. Thought I tried that on my own, but seems to work now.

```
function hasIndexSignature(v: any): v is {[index: string]: any} {
  return typeof v === 'object'
}

let foo: any = ...
if (hasIndexSignature(foo)) {
  for (const property in value) {
    foo[property] = transformIt(foo[property])
  }
}
```